# The SAML Request AssertionConsumerServiceURL is invalid - Auth0, SAML, Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, saml-2.0, auth0

I'm trying to integrate SSO with Kibana and SAML. I'm using Auth0.
Following are my settings in yml files

```
kibana.yml
elasticsearch.hosts: ["https://localhost:9200"]
xpack.security.enabled: true
elasticsearch.ssl.certificate: D:/Piyusha/Extracted/kibana-7.4.1-windows-x86_64/config/certs/client.cer
elasticsearch.ssl.key: D:/Piyusha/Extracted/kibana-7.4.1-windows-x86_64/config/certs/client.key
elasticsearch.ssl.certificateAuthorities: D:/Piyusha/Extracted/kibana-7.4.1-windows-x86_64/config/certs/client-ca.cer
elasticsearch.ssl.verificationMode: certificate

xpack.security.authc.providers: [saml]
xpack.security.authc.saml.realm: saml1
server.xsrf.whitelist: [/api/security/v1/saml]

elasticsearch.yml

xpack.security.enabled: true

xpack.security.transport.ssl.enabled: true
xpack.security.transport.ssl.verification_mode: certificate
xpack.security.transport.ssl.keystore.path: certs/elastic-certificates.p12
xpack.security.transport.ssl.truststore.path: certs/elastic-certificates.p12

xpack.security.http.ssl.enabled: true
xpack.security.http.ssl.keystore.path: certs/elastic-certificates.p12
xpack.security.http.ssl.truststore.path: certs/elastic-certificates.p12
xpack.security.http.ssl.client_authentication: optional

xpack.security.authc.realms.pki.pki1.order: 0

xpack.security.authc.token.enabled: true
xpack.security.authc.realms.saml.saml1:
  order: 2
  idp.metadata.path: saml/dev-zl4z3q20_auth0_com-metadata.xml
  sp.entity_id:  "http://localhost:5601"
  idp.entity_id: "urn:dev-zl4z3q20.auth0.com"
  sp.acs: "http://localhost:5601/api/security/v1/saml"
  sp.logout: "http://localhost:5601/logout"
  attributes.principal: "urn:oid:0.9.2342.19200300.100.1.1"
  attributes.groups: "urn:oid:1.3.6.1.4.1.5923.1.5.1."
```

Before adding saml settings, everything worked perfect like authentication, etc. But after adding saml configurations, kibana url redirects to error page

```
https://dev-zl4z3q20.auth0.com/samlp/brGsd0sUh18u1oremCeu58L4FxrExgxf?SAMLRequest=fVJbb9sgGP0riHfb4FtSFKfKkmWLlHVR4%2FRhLxPGuEHC4PLhLO2vn3Pp1ElVXuHcOIfJ%2FbHV6CAdKGsKTEOCkTTC1so8F3hXLoMxvp9OgLc67tis93vzKF96CR4NRAPsclPg3hlmOShghrcSmBdsO%2FuxZnFIWOest8JqjGYA0vnBam4N9K10W%2BkOSsjd47rAe%2B87FkXaCq73FjzLckIj3qkIpOid8q%2FRgUYnQ4wWQwJluD%2BnPhFhYNbyELzp9C15iUnIh6wkFLY9M7qoct%2BgJrDb03FPrZPtXPbZeJ0uj%2B7r8fnYYLRaFPh3mjUiz0iV8CRPBaWjOq5jwZPxuBqleU6qu0aMuEgHOEAvVwY8N77AMaF3ASVBQksaszhlWRzmGf2F0eb6%2Bi%2FKXFq9VVV1AQH7XpabYPNzW2L09L7OAMDXLdjZ3X0c4bYwf28eTz%2FteRJ91P23%2BMMgtFpsrFbiFc20tn%2FmTnIvC9xwDRKjpXUt97e9TyeqDpozlHnHDShpPI6mV9f%2Ff9b0Lw%3D%3D
```

and gives following error

```
invalid_request: The SAML Request AssertionConsumerServiceURL is invalid: 'http://localhost:5601/api/security/v1/saml'
TRACKING ID: c682d69fc2f95872f203
```

Comment: it looks like it means the IdP has a different sp.acs from what is in kibana.yml

Comment: @codebrane and how to check sp.acs in IdP?

Comment: The IdP should have metadata about the SP. If it's value for ACS doesn't match sp.acs you can see that error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error indicates that the ACS URL being sent in the SAML Request does not match what is configured in Auth0.

Verify that in the Auth0 application's SAML addon settings you have set `http://localhost:5601/api/security/v1/saml` as the ACS URL.